# Using PureLayout library pinEdge right UIView in UIScrollView not working or how-to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, pure-layout

I'm using **PureLayout** library. [Github](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout)

I've **`UIScrollView`** as a fullscreen container.

As a simple example, I've a **UIView(0,0,100,50)**. I want to pin this view's right edge to right edge of `UIScrollView`.

I'm doing it this way:

```
UIScrollView *sv = [UIScrollView newAutoLayoutView];
sv.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;
[self.view addSubview:sv];
[sv autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

UIView *v = [UIView newAutoLayoutView];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[v autoSetDimensionsToSize:CGSizeMake(100, 50)];
[sv addSubview:v];
[v autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeTop withInset:15];
[v autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeRight withInset:15];
//[v autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeTrailing withInset:15]; // also tried this
```

I get **result**:

[image]

I know, I can create a **UIView container** with same **width** as `UIScrollView`, and add it as `subview` of `scrollView` and put all custom views into this container, but I wonder why we **can't** do it with `UIScrollView` **directly**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case, someone is bothering with same issue, there is an answer from the owner of **PureLayout**, he answers my question:
https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout/issues/61#issuecomment-93819808